# Finding the center point between two points on a plane

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

#### Challenge:

To take two points on the plane and figure out the position of the point that's a) on the line that connects them, and b) equally distant from each of the original points.

#### Example:

```
(0,0), (3,3) -> (1.5,1.5)

(-1,-1), (1,1) -> (0,0)

(-7,3), (2,-2) -> (-2.5,0.5)

(3, 1), (-5,9) -> (-1,5)
```

#### Rules:

- The input and output can be a tuple, array, list, or any other type of sequence.
- There must be two inputs, each representing a point.
- The output has to support floating point numbers.

Shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: Some more test cases would probably be a good idea. Maybe `((-2,3), (5,4))`, `((-7,-5),(-7,-5))` would be a good start.

Comment: May input be two complex numbers? May output be a complex number?

Comment: Is there any relevance of the "on a plane" part? Any two arbitrary points share infinitely many planes, and the desired point is shared by all of them.

Comment: @JulianWolf I take "point on a plane" to signify a 2d coordinate system.

Comment: @Sparr: that makes sense, thanks. I guess my mind treats "on a plane" as being distinct from "on *the* plane". (This is probably due to me not talking to enough actual mathematicians.)

Comment: contrast to "point on a line" or "point in a volume/space"

Comment: Can we take input as a list containing both pairs?

Comment: @Riker. No, there must be two input values, each representing a single point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-5 bytes (ha ha, yes I am an idiot) thanks to FryAmTheEggman!

```
+H
```

Takes two lists each of length d and returns one list of length d where d is the dimensions of the Cartesian space (question is posed for 2 dimensions, but should work for any d).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@6/t8f///2hdcx3j2P/RRjq6RrEA)**

#### How?

```
+H - Main link: a, b (lists of coordinates)
+  - add (vectorises across the dimensions)
 H - halve (vectorises across the result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 4 bytes

```
Mean
```

Works on lists of vectors: for example, `Mean[{{-7, 3}, {2, -2}}]` returns `{-5/2, 1/2}`. (If the input consists of floating-point numbers, so will the output.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```python
lambda*x:[sum(a)/2for a in zip(*x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S1OwVYj5n5OYm5SSqFVhFV1cmquRqKlvlJZfpJCokJmnUJVZoKFVoRn7v6AoM69EI02Di0tBIVrXXEfBOFZHIdpIR0HXKJaLS1PzPwA)

Comment: If you place an `*` before the first `x` (for 0 bytes) it will actually take multiple (and variable) arguments rather than the single (wrapped) list.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks! I didn't know that was possible, but it does look neater and more clean.

Answer (score 1):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
zipWith$((/2).).(+)
```

Can be called with `(zipWith$((/2).).(+)) (p1::[a]) (p2::[a])` where `a` is any type deriving `Fractional`. Works in arbitrary dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 8 bytes

```
.5(L₁+L₂
```

Takes input on List 1 and List 2. Works for all dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

### [Julia](https://julialang.org/) 0.6, 13 bytes

```
(x->x/2)∘(+)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>70</s> <s>54</s> 49 bytes

*Thanks to @Julian Wolf for helping to save a bunch of bytes!*

```
(defun f(a b)(mapcar(lambda(c d)(/(+ c d)2))a b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/clisp#dYzBCoMwEETvfsUeZxCtSQ9@z2oMCFHE2u9Ps5JeCj3Mso99Oxlhie9dIlQmYtNj1hNJtykoZgnEA63Y4klTmHGc634JoiCtr0uGfrCw4rNgCcnm1@xcudn4usbujzvWnsreXv3t5g8)

Comment: `car` and `cadr` can shave a bunch of bytes off of those calls to `nth`. `mapcar` is also your friend.

Comment: @JulianWolf Thanks! I don't really know Lisp, so that was of a lot of help.

Comment: No problem! LISP is super duper awesome once you get the hang of it. The next step would be putting both operations into a single lambda—no need to call `mapcar` separately for addition and division.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript , 30 bytes

valid for any number of dimensions

```javascript
a=>b=>a.map((c,i)=>(c+b[i])/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9n2hrl2Rrl6iXm1igoZGsk6lpa6eRrJ0UnRmrqW@k@T85P684PydVLyc/XSNNI9pQxyRWUyPaSMcgVlOT6z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 22 bytes

As an unnamed function that takes 2 vectors as parameters.  Simply returns the mean of input vectors the same as a lot of answers.

```
function(a,b)((a+b)/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@6/BlVaal1ySmZ@nkaiTpKmhkaidpKlvpMmlqZGsYahjpKmTrGGqY6qp@f8/AA)

And 16 bytes using the pryr library

```
pryr::f((a+b)/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Python](https://www.python.org/) + [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), 18 bytes

```
lambda a,b:(a+b)/2
```

Works in two dimensions for points inputted as imaginary numbers, or (since OP specifies that inputs must be taken as sequences) in arbitrary dimensions for points inputted as NumPy arrays.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#VcxBCsMgEIXhfU4xyxk6tmoWhUBPYlyMFEGoRiRZ5PRWSjZ9y@/BH@EFa/9IDm8B4bCg3AI97JRy3doO5cj17HFrkCAVcA41a2KceSbP4FAZVmaAYXPBc1yMlpUl75cJxmpLZceIv9pdWpMTk9Oe@F@MJ6L@BQ)

Comment: Thanks for the TIO link, @Riker! I really ought to get into the habit of adding those.

Answer (score 0):

## Math.JS, 14 bytes

```
f(a,b)=(a+b)/2
```

Creates function `f` which takes 2 One Dimensional Matricies as input.

As expected, this just adds the two, then halfs the result.

[Try it!](http://a-ta.co/math/f(a%2Cb)%3D(a%2Bb)%2F2%0A%0Aprint(%0A%20%20%20%20f(%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%5B3%2C3%5D)%0A))

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 13 bytes

```
a->b->(a+b)/2
```

Call with currying syntax, i.e. `(a->b->(a+b)/2)([1,2])([3,4])`.

Comment: Shoot, didn't see that you'd beat me to this one

Comment: @JulianWolf it's not a problem! Yours is actually a byte shorter, so you can definitely leave it up. I don't even have v0.6, so I think tha'ts pretty cool.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely leaving the composition solution up (they seem sufficiently different); there's no need for the two equivalent v0.5 solutions to stay though

Comment: Not familiar with Julia specifically, but could you save a byte with currying to `a->b->(a+b)/2`?

Comment: @Cyoce yes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Python + NumPy, 17 bytes

```
lambda a:sum(a)/2
```

A slightly less boring version of the other python answer. Takes args as 1 numpy array, containing both pairs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#Zc2xCsMwDATQPV@hUQK5jZ2hEOiXpB5UikFQO0ZNhny9GzK0lN508DguwRVu7Sn5/hCQ8bVmFDqHTnOdbYGy5rq1NBsoaIGpg08m7LknxoEHigw/4jw7v5tn/2@XfcAY2AWKX4nj0atpWTDhcXwSM9lQiai9AQ)

Comment: Does this not work in normal Python?

Comment: @Cyoce Python doesn't support division across a vector.

Comment: nvm. I see it now.